# SqlException error occurs on cursor use

Tags: android, cursor

on the cursor line this error occurs.

```
Error:

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax 
error: , while compiling: SELECT value FROM system WHERE (name= ) ORDER BY name
```

The cursor looks like this:

```
 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://settings/system"),
 values, "name=", fields, "name");
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        long lvalue = c.getLong(0);
        if (lvalue > 0) {
            m_ScreenSaverDelay = lvalue;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://settings/system"), values, "name= '"+ theNameyouArelookingFor +"'", fields, "name");
```

your query should evaluate to:

```
SELECT value FROM system WHERE (name='ThenameYouAreLookingFor') ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Note that, in the above example, 1) `fields` will be completely ignored, and 2) it may be susceptible to SQL injection attacks, which the documented way of parameter binding should eliminate.

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29) states:

> You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values
>   from selectionArgs, in the order that they appear in the selection.
>   The values will be bound as Strings.

So try `"name=?s"` instead of `"name="` which will eventually be evaluated to something equivalent to

`"name=\"" + fields[0] + "\""`

(not taking quoting of the data input into account in this example which will (or *should*) be done by the DB engine).